# OpenGL Texture Rendering issue

Tags: c++, opengl

I have copied the QImage into OpenGL Texture below.  If I want to render the Texture, should I
just bind the Texture in Flush() ? Or should I have to do anything else? Please find my below
code

```
  void   SaveBackBuffer() {
          QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(this->winId());
          QImage buf = pixmap.toImage();
         _savedBackBuffer = buf.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
  }

  void  RestoreBackBuffer() {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _scrTex);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _savedBackBuffer.width(), 
                   _savedBackBuffer.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                   _savedBackBuffer.bits());
    
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
       _bSavingBackBuffer = false;

  } 
 
  Flush() {

       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _scrTex);  
       ...
       glDrawArrays...
  }
```

Comment: You can't render a texture. You have to render a quad and apply the texture to it.

Comment: any code sample ?  Like how to apply the texture

Comment: Every basic OpenGL tutorial should cover this. For example, https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures

Comment: Thanks BDL.  Actually what I am trying to do is grab the openGL Widget which has some graphics on it and save it as QImage in openGL format.  The RestoreBackBuffer () will take the QImage and copy it to texture.  So when I do the PAN or move the canvas  I am trying the put back image or texture so that I want to avoid redraw on the screen. Can this be done? I have texture  ready just don't know how should I copy on the OpenglWidget?  What should be my Quad co-ordinates then? any pointers?